Sample size calculation within-subject
I need to conduct a sample size analysis for an experiment with the following characteristics:
One intra-subject independent variable is the type of cheese with two levels, Cheese A (1) and Cheese B (2).
The other intra-subject independent variable is the tasting round with three levels: blind tasting round (1), expectation tasting round (2), and informed tasting round (3).
The dependent variables are five quasi-symmetric variables from 1 to 7 depending on how much the consumer liked the two cheeses over the three tasting rounds.
Thus, the dependent variables are: Flavour, Smell, Texture, Aftertaste and Overall impression scoring each dependent variable according to a quasi-symmetric scale from 1 to 7.
All subjects of the experiment will taste cheese A and cheese B in the three planned tasting rounds evaluating in each of them the five attributes: Flavour, Smell, Texture, Aftertaste and Overall Impression scoring each dependent variable according to a quasi-symmetric scale from 1 to 7.
We expect a small medium size , the significance level is fixed at 5%, the power is set at 0.8
I need to calculate the sample size needed to carry out such a study.
Could you help me know if I am using the correct test?
I'm using the next code in R:
library(WebPower)
wp.rmanova(ng = 2, nm = 3, f = 0.25, nscor = 1, 
           alpha = 0.05, power =0.8, type = 2)    


No, that's not correct. ng means number of between-person factor levels, so for you that would be 1, because you only have within-subject factors. Unfortunately WebPower does not support power calculations for two within factors. The newer package Superpower does, though.

There's a Superpower Shiny App, which is quite easy to use: https://shiny.ieis.tue.nl/anova_power/
